# Insert all divs with same class into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, html

I want to insert all divs which have the class .page into an array, then call each using the array iteration. For example the array pages[] should allow me to add certain effect to the div in pages[2].

Comment: Do you have some sample code to share? Instead of adding the divs to an array you could use index() - http://api.jquery.com/index/ - or the ':eq' selector.

Comment: Why don't you use $("div.page:eq(2)") instead of building an array ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, came in handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do like this ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      var arr=[];
      $(".page").each(function(){ arr.push($(this));});
      $.each(arr,function(key,val){ val.css('color','gray')});  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>.page content will be colored in gray.</b><br/><br/>
<div class="dontDo">The quick </div>
<div class="page">brown fox jumps</div>
<div class="doIt"> over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="page"> over the lazy dog</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var pageDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
for(i = 0; i < pageDivs.length;i++)
{
    //apply your effects using pageDivs[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in some of browsers getElementByClassName is not supported.However you can use calssName property like this :

```
function getElementsByClassName( strClassName, obj ) {
    if ( obj.className == strClassName ) {
        //insert this elm into array 
        array.push(obj);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.getElementsByClassName [is not supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) < IE8.  If you aren't worried about that, then Sunil's response will work for you.

If you want [the jQuery way](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(".page").each(function(index) {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Happy iterating.